# react-router: Navigating to URL works but pushState complains "did not match any routes"

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When I do the following:

```
routeToCreateCreatives() {
  this.props.pushState(null, 'create');
}
```

It changes the URL just fine:
    http://localhost:3000/campaign/SLUG/creatives/create

But I receive this warning:

```
Warning: Location "creatives/create" did not match any routes
```

The weird thing is when I refresh the page or navigate to the URL, it loads.

Here are my nested routes:

```
<Route path="/campaign/:campaignId" component={Campaign}>
  <IndexRoute component={CampaignDashboard} />
  <Route path="dashboard" component={CampaignDashboard}/>
  <Route path="creatives" component={Creatives}/>
  <Route path="creatives/create" component={CreativesCreate}/>
</Route>
```

Finally, if I use an absolute path like the one below, the links work. It feels like there is some issue using pushState with the :campaignId slug.

```
pushState(null, `/campaign/${campaign.id}/creatives`);
```

Comment: `pushState` just takes the absolute path